# TypeScript new class that extends String

Tags: typescript, primitive-types

I am currently trying to set up a class "AdvancedString". This class should extend String by methods like e.g. isJSON. Currently it looks like this

```
class AdvancedString extends String {
    isJSON():boolean{
        var itIs = true;
        try{
            JSON.parse(this.toString());
        } catch (err) {
            itIs = false;
        }       

        return itIs;
    }
}

export{ AdvancedString}
```

now it doesn't work too bad. If I create the a new instance with "SampleString" I'll get

```
let sample = new AdvancedString("SampleString");
// ExtendedString {[[PrimitiveValue]]: "SampleString"}
```

and if I do toString i get back the correct value

```
sample.toString()
// "SampleString"
```

However I would like for it to behave like a normal string when i call it directly so

```
sample === "SampleString"
// should return true and sample.toString() === "SampleString"
// should not be necessary
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in TypeScript or is this not possible? I would like to use a separate class and not add my method to the prototype of string

Comment: FWIW, I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853116/157247) with a note about possible downsides...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`===` requires the types to be the same. Instances of your `AdvancedString` type don't have the same type as either primitive or object strings, and so `===` will always be false. `new String("") === ""` is also false, for the same reason; the former is a String object, the latter is a primitive string.

Your `AdvancedString` is `==` primitive strings, but only (it seems) if you use `class` natively; when I [try that in the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20AdvancedString%20extends%20String%20%7B%0A%20%20isJSON()%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20itIs%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20JSON.parse(this.toString())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20catch%20(err)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20itIs%20%3D%20false%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20itIs%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20s%20%3D%20new%20AdvancedString(%22foo%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(s%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22foo%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20false%0Aconsole.log(s%20%3D%3D%20%22foo%22)%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20true) with TypeScript transpiling the `class` syntax, it fails. But it works natively:

```js
class AdvancedString extends String {
  isJSON() {
    var itIs = true;
    try {
      JSON.parse(this.toString());
    } catch (err) {
      itIs = false;
    }

    return itIs;
  }
}

const s = new AdvancedString("foo");
console.log(s === "foo"); // false
console.log(s == "foo");  // true
```

**However**, you might want to consider the downsides of using `AdvancedString`, since your strings will be objects, not primitives:

- Memory impact. Allocating those string objects has a bigger memory impact than using primitive strings.¹
- Any code receiving one of your strings (for instance, a library you might be using) that does a `typeof` check will not see them as (primitive) strings. So an API accepting a string or an options object, for instance, will likely be misled if you pass it an `AdvancedString` instance. TypeScript may not be able to warn you when this happens, depending on how the library is annotated (`string|object`, for instance, wouldn't catch it).

---

¹ Out of curiousity, I did this:

```
const s = "**y";
const a = Array.from({length: 100000}, () => new String("x" * s));
```

...on an otherwise-blank page. I ended up with 100,005 `String` instances in memory (I guess there were 5 from somewhere else) occupying 3,200,160 bytes. In contrast, this:

```
const s = "**y";
const a = Array.from({length: 100000}, () => "x" + s);
```

...only increased the number of primitive strings from 3,830 (281,384 bytes) to 27,533 (1,040,120 bytes); apparently some (but not all) of them were reused.

So that's ~741kB for primitives vs. ~3MB for objects, a bit over four times the memory.

That's just one synthetic test, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible, unfortunately. An object is still an object and is not `===` to primitive value (string).

Trust me I've spent dozens of hours on this problem, you simply can't do anything.

You can mutate String.prototype.isJSON

```
String.prototype.isJson = () => 'your logic here'
```

But that's not very clean solution, unless you are sure that this code stays inside your app only.

P.S. Typescript has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the anser. Sadly I kind of expected that :(

Comment: *"...so that no one without access to the symbol can access the method..."* That's incorrect: `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(String.prototype)` will give access to that Symbol to any code that asks for it. Symbols do not provide any form of privacy at all.

Comment: *"`String.prototype.isJson = () => 'your logic here`"* Never extend built-in prototypes with *enumerable* properties. Something, somewhere, is going to fall over as a result. If you extend built-in prototypes (which can be okay in certain limited contexts), use `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: Oh really? Didn't know about that. Thank you. So it just makes it harder. Making it non-enumerable will help a bit too.